Надо чтобы код работал без паузы
from pyrogram import Client
import asyncio
import time

API_ID = 20336506
API_HASH = '53df51966cc63f31020bb504ab7fe446'

async def clone_channel(source_channel_ids: list, target_chanel_id: int):
    client = Client(name='client', api_id=API_ID, api_hash=API_HASH)

    await client.start()

    try:
        replace_list = [('https://telegram.me/joinchat/AAAAAEfPbzByz7MhJXcSAA', '@buzzboxnews'),('Qo\'qonliklar','BuzzBox'),('t.me/UFCuz_official','@buzzboxnews')]

        for source_channel_id in source_channel_ids:
            try:
                messages = client.get_chat_history(chat_id=source_channel_id, limit=1)

                async for message in messages:
                    if message.caption:
                        for old, new in replace_list:
                            message.caption = message.caption.replace(old, new)
                    await message.copy(chat_id=target_channel_id, caption=message.caption)
                    time.sleep(3)  # Pause for 1 second
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
                print(traceback.format_exc())
    finally:
        await client.stop() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    source_channel_ids = [-1001204776752, -1001456172102]  # Add more source channel IDs to this list
    target_channel_id = -1002036926923
    asyncio.run(clone_channel(source_channel_ids=source_channel_ids, target_chanel_id=target_channel_id))







сейсас после копирования контента, сразу выполнение кода остановливается.
